# Installing Ruby Version Manager AFTER ruby on rails installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This might be a paranoid question, but am I likely to break anything in my ruby on rails app if I install RVM AFTER having installed rails?

Thanks in advance for any peace of mind you can offer me :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App will be fine - but after installing RVM it will take some configuration get everything running back the way it was. This has nothing to do with your app, but with your environment. If you follow the installation instructions EXACTLY then it will not be too difficult.

If you are planning to do this on a production server then be prepared for some downtime.